# Any way to start subprocess inside a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to be able to fork and exec an artbitrary subprocess in javascript. Is there any support for something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, but HTML5 has [Web workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute binary code from a Chrome extension unless you use an PPAPI or NPAPI plugin (which means you would have to compile your plugin for all the target platforms).